# Alternative to copyTo or setValues?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, setvalue

I'm currently copying one tab of a sheet to a completely different sheet as a backup.  I use `copyTo()` for this because I want to copy the entire tab.  When I update this backup, I use `getValues()` -> `setValues()` to overwrite the previous data with a particular range so as not to overwrite the formulas within the headers.  But of course what happens is all of my data validations within the array that were set during `copyTo()` get overwritten with static data.

What function should I use that will not only copy the values but also the data validations (maybe even the formulas)?  I would use `copyTo()` again, but the sheet name already exists.  Would renaming the sheet first and then copying be the way to go?

Comment: Why don't you just copy the entire sheet?

Comment: I only need about 5 of the some 30 tabs on the sheet to be backed up. Everything else is data while these few tabs are all selected data validations. This way, when I make changes to the data, I don’t have to do it to every copy of the sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need to apply data validation rather than just copyTo again there is some help here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation

Otherwise renaming the old copy or deleting it if you don't need it is a simple solution.

Comment: I decided to go ahead and temporarily rename the tab before deleting (in case something goes wrong before the copyTo) and then just copy the tab again. It may be a bit clumsy, but it is working for my purposes so far. Thank you for your answer!